# Efficiently spreading vectors in space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently stuck on the following problem, any idea is more than welcome :

Is it possible to find two positive integers $m,n$ and a matrix $M \in \mathbb{M}_{n,m}(\mathbb{R})$ such that:

- $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}, y^TM$ has **at least** two positive coordinates.
- $\forall i \leq m-1, \exists y_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $y_i^TM:=\begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(i)}&\dots&x_m^{(i)}\end{bmatrix}$ has **exactly** two positive coordinates, the $i^{th}$ one and the last one (so $x_i^{(i)}$ and $x_m^{(i)}$).
  ?

  This problem can be reworded to get a more geometric perspective :
  For any hyperplane $H$ i will call $H+$ and $H-$ the two half spaces that it defines.
  Suppose you have a family of vectors $B$ such that for any hyperplane $H$, at least one element of $B$ is pointing towards $H+$ and at least one is pointing toward $H-$.
  Suppose that $B$ is minimal for this property : no proper subset of $B$ is like that.
  (So basically what i'm saying is that the vectors in $B$ are "well spread" : the convex cone of $B$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if i remove any element it is not $\mathbb{R}^n$ anymore.)
  Add exactly one vector to $B$. Could it happen that for any hyperplane $H$, you now have at least **two** elements of $B \cup \{v\}$ pointing towards H+ and at least two elements of $B \cup \{v\}$ pointing towards H- ?

  I strongly believe that the answer to this problem is "not possible", mostly because of the second formulation of the problem : i feel like if i take two elements $b_1, b_2 \in B$ such that the angle between them is really big, then the vector $v$ that i add can hardly be in the same halfspaces as $b_1$ and the same ones as $b_2$, but obviously this argument is not a proof...

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: Yeah, you're right i forgot to say that this only applies for $y \neq 0$. Also yes i'm talking about the coordinates.

Comment: It might be easier to think about the subspace of $\mathbb R^m$ which is the row space of $M$, necessarily of dimension $n$ since $y^T M = 0$ can only have the trivial solution.